# Previous svn log is not displayed

Tags: svn, cvs2svn

Firstly, I  have migrated my CVS repository into SVN repository. I checked out this whole SVN repository and  make some changes like rearranging the directories into branches and tags. The I imported it into the new SVN repository. I am using following command to import ..

```
svn import svn+ssh://host/address/path to repository -m "new files added" --username xyz
```

After authenticating xyz, it gets imported.

Now I am checking out that repository into working copy. I used following command

```
svn co svn+ssh://host/address/path to repository  --username xyz
```

When I do `svn log`   I get the  `new files added`  as log output. All the previous logs are not displayed. I want those logs to be displayed.How can I get those logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain files' history, use `svn cp` and `svn mv` in the initial repository instead of importing the files to a new repository.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In case if i need to put those project files into another repository, is there any ways so that i can retain the history too?

Comment: No, the history is maintained in the repository, usually there's no problem because there needs to be a leading place to put stuff (even if you were to use a DVCS)

Comment: I am not expert in SVN. I could not properly get you. Could you please elaborate it? Shall I go for svn copy and manipulate the already existing repository or I can still retain history in new repository too?

Comment: Normally you work in one repository, so there's no need to copy it somewhere else with history.

Answer (score 1):

when you `svn import` files into Subversion, you create an initial version of those files. The files can't have more history than what you're currently seeing, because before the import there weren't tracked by svn.

Comment: Is there anyway to retain the previous log information?I need to manipulate the repository architecture and put it into another repository. But those log information is also very important for me. Can you please suggest me any ideas for it?

Comment: You build the history when you change the files in your working copy and commit them. I suggest that you read the svnbook, to catch up on how everything works